# how do you prove that sin is a function of arclength(radian) to y coordinate?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I was watching https://youtu.be/TpWQlKHPyJ4

what it does is the following

- calculate the arclength of a unit circle in terms of x

integrate $(1-x^2)^{-1/2}$
you get arclength = $sin^-1$(x)

and the professor says this is the first time `sin` and `arclength` are defined

I'm like *aha* *wow* , that is interesting.

But then, it's confusing when I try to understand what he means.
Here's my interpretation, wonder if is reasonable

you can write a definition for arcsine in terms of definite integral (2nd fundamental theorem of calculus) then you can also show that arclength of a different radius circle is proportional to the radius
by change of variable,
ie, you can prove that circle's circumference is proportional to the radius

Then you can go on to define `sine` and calculate area of circle by integration and calculate derivate of sine and so on.

On the other end,

I could have arrived at the conclusion where circumference of a circle is proportional to the radius via a different way
ie. by limit of n-gon inscribed in a circle.
Then, from here on, you can also define `sine`

So his way of reasoning goes from defining arcsine first then define sine but I can see one can define first then define arcsine

Am I missing what he's saying when he says `arcsine` is first defined.

- edit

I didn't mention `angle` in my reasoning. I was saying that you can arrive at the conclusion where defining a function sine in terms of arclength is sensical from two ways. one following the video lecture and one using the n-gon argument.
Once we establish the arclength is proportional to the radius, one can define sine in terms of arclength of unit circle.

What I asked can be rephrased as ...
I can use his method to come to the conclusion that defining sine in terms of arclength is sensical
The axioms to establish this is fundamental of calculus 2 and chain rule.

And I can use another method to get to the same conclusion.
The axioms used here is `similar triangle` and definition of circle as n-gon, and property of limits

Excerpting from "Calculus Volume 1, 2nd Edition" (Tom Apostol):

- The sine and cosine functions are defined for all real numbers.
- $\cos(0) = \sin(\pi/2) = 1, ~\cos(\pi) = -1.$
- $\cos(y - x) = \cos(y)\cos(x) + \sin(y)\sin(x).$
- For $0 < x < (\pi/2)~$ : 
  $\displaystyle 0 < \cos(x) < \frac{\sin(x)}{x} < \frac{1}{cos(x)}.$

Well the 4th property can be derived from `arclength propotional to radius`.
Although the axioms he choose will surely work, it seems to me it is rather peculiar starting points to define sine.
Well at least, I would have to ponder why those axioms implies radian as domain of sine and if they are minimal axioms (I guess I have hard time guessing how one would feel justified in thinking those are minimal axioms)

umm why the formatting is so hard to read..

Comment: This seems like a bizarre question.  The way that I was taught, in Real Analysis (AKA Calculus) the *common sense* definition of the sine and cosine functions are radically altered, to facilitate attacking certain problems.  See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4512723/intuitive-understanding-of-why-trigonometric-functions-relate-to-both-triangles/4535093#4535093) for the approach taken in "Calculus, Volume 1" (2nd Edition, 1966, Tom Apostol).  That answer seems to be in conflict with your posting.  ...see next comment

Comment: That is, the sine and cosine functions are, **by definition**,  functions of the arclength, which is a real number, rather than being functions of the angle.

Comment: "umm why the formatting is so hard to read.." - Before now, I didn't know that putting four spaces at the beginning of a paragraph did anything. Anyway, you could instead try putting `>` at the beginning of a paragraph.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: @user2661923 I edited op as comments got too long..

Comment: "Well the 4th property can be derived from arclength propotional to radius" : I guess that I didn't explain the point of these axioms well enough.  Apostol is saying that if you accept the axioms, then normal trig formulas, including the integrals/derivatives (and thus the Taylor series) are derivable.  Apostol is **not** saying that the trig functions are based on the arclength. ...see next comment

Comment: Instead, what Apostol is saying is that once you accept the axioms, you can then check whether the normal trig functions work (**i.e. satisfy the axioms**), with the change that the sine and cosine will be based on the arclength on the unit circle.  Then, Apostol says that you can prove **geometrically** that under this construance of the sine and cosine functions, his axioms are satisfied.  So, you don't prove the axioms by Geometry.  Instead, you verify that the altered construance, based on unit circle arc length, satisfies the axioms.